# How to get content from one html to another html using JS

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to make one navbar in a couple of HTML files, I'm trying to get content from `index.html id="sample"`, and paste it in the same HTML and in another HTML called `template.html` but I get errors in all files, those are at the same level.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("sample");
var navbarass = nav.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("indexnav").appendChild(navbarass.cloneNode(true));
document.getElementById("temlatesnav").appendChild(navbarass.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: Why not use "document.getElementById('navigation').innerHTML = Your nav html" insider your JS file and then have a element with id navigation on every page?

Comment: what the errors you got?